# создание background через переопределение paintComponent

Tags: java, background

помогите разобраться, хочу сделать background (добивать изображение на основной фон), собственно добавление идет строками

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("bg.jpg"));
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
```

в итоге он жалуется на **read(new File("bg.jpg")** , мол это необработанный тип исключения, и просит добавить IOException, но добавить его в painComponent я тоже не могу - несовмещенный тип.
Помогите разобраться что к чему, и как это есть.

сам исходник

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class GameField extends JPanel {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private final int SIZE = 13;
    private int cellHeight;

    public GameField(){

    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();
        cellHeight = height/SIZE;
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("bg.jpg"));
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);                         
        g.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(width/2, 0, width/2, height);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
            g.drawLine(width/2, i*cellHeight, width,i*cellHeight);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Дык поместите ваш блок `image = ImageIO.read(new File("bg.jpg"));` в `try..catch` и всё

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `paintComponent` может вызываться очень часто, поэтому читать файл в нём не стоит. Да и архитектурно это сомнительное решение. Лучше перенести считывание в конструктор:

```
public class GameField extends JPanel {
    ...
    private BufferedImage image;

    public GameField() throws IOException {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("bg.jpg"));
    }

    ...
}
```